# How to match whole string using php

Tags: php, preg-match

I have two arrays:

```
 $search = array('A/OPTION-1/z','/OPTION-2/','/OPTION-3/','/OPTION-4/','/OPTION-5/','/OPTION-6/','/OPTION-7/','/OPTION-8/',
            '/OPTION-9/','/OPTION-10/','/OPTION-11/','/OPTION-12/','/OPTION-13/','/OPTION-14/','/OPTION-15/','/OPTION-16/','/OPTION-17/',
            '/OPTION-18/','/OPTION-19/');
```

and want to replace with:

```
$replace = array('<b class="option" id="1" >OPTION 1</b><hr>',
            '<b class="option" id="2">OPTION 2</b><hr>',
            '<b class="option" id="3">OPTION 3</b><hr>',
            '<b class="option" id="4">OPTION 4</b><hr>',
            '<b class="option" id="5">OPTION 5</b><hr>',
            '<b class="option" id="6">OPTION 6</b><hr>',
            '<b class="option" id="7">OPTION 7</b><hr>',
            '<b class="option" id="8">OPTION 8</b><hr>',
            '<b class="option" id="9">OPTION 9</b><hr>',
            '<b class="option" id="10">OPTION 10</b><hr>',
            '<b class="option" id="11">OPTION 11</b><hr>',
            '<b class="option" id="12">OPTION 12</b><hr>',
            '<b class="option" id="13">OPTION 13</b><hr>',
            '<b class="option" id="14">OPTION 14</b><hr>',
            '<b class="option" id="15">OPTION 15</b><hr>',
            '<b class="option" id="16">OPTION 16</b><hr>',
            '<b class="option" id="17">OPTION 17</b><hr>',
            '<b class="option" id="18">OPTION 18</b><hr>',
            '<b class="option" id="19">OPTION 19</b><hr>');
```

and the response is:

```
 OPTION-1 AX
 OPTION-11 AX
 OPTION-12 AX
 OPTION-13 AX
```

The problem is while I replace OPTION-1 it works fine, but when I replacing OPTION-11 it replaces OPTION-11 into OPTION-1 and it should be OPTION-11.

Comment: `$` matches the end of string in PCRE

Comment: I don't understand, are you trying to replace `OPTION X` with `<b class="option" id="X">OPTION X</b><hr>`?

Comment: i am trying to search OPTION-1 and Want to REPLACE <b class="option" id="1" >OPTION 1</b> using preg_replace($search,$replace,$pqreplace,-1);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this general rule to catch any `OPTION X` strings and replace them:

```
preg_replace("/OPTION (\d+)/i", "<b class="option" id="$1">OPTION $1</b><hr>", $subject_string);
```

Comment: +1 for nice solution :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to change order of your "replacements". Run replaces for options with bigger numbers first.

Answer (score 0):

i was going to suggest changing the order of the array as well

you can use http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reverse.php to do this.

Answer (score 0):

use word boundary (ie. `\b`) :

```
$search = array('/\bOPTION-1\b/', '/\bOPTION-2\b/', ... );
```